# Unable to start debugging on web server, localhost subdomain

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, iis-7

I am using VS2013, IIS7, and have set a subdomain in IIS and my hosts file to point to 127.0.0.1.
I've created the secondary website, and have the http binding in IIS pointing to localhost.subdomain.com.

Things i've tried:

1. IISReset
2. Deleting Site in IIS, Deleting app pools, re-building from scratch
3. Cleaning/Re-building solution/Restarting Computer/Visual Studio
4. Creating Virtual Directory through VS, even tried tying to IISExpress to no avail.

Also, i can go directly to the site in a browser just fine using the http://localhost.subdomain.com and traverse through it all, it just fails to load into Visual Studio for debugging.  All debug info is set correctly through project properties as well.

There are a bunch of people within my office with the exact same setups that i've sat down with that work fine on their machines, but not on mine.  I've exhausted my google and microsoft.com searches at this point, any suggestion would help.

Comment: add on a page that `Debug.Fail("test");` or that `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` and run this page to see if the debug pop up

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is unable to resolve the domain because it likely hasn't been added to your hosts file.

If you edit the hosts file found at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` to include your subdomain:

```
# rest of hosts file here

127.0.0.1       api.localhost
```

Then your debugger should start working again.